# Bits of Number in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, floating-point, bit-manipulation

In flash, performing bitwise operations on Number always strips away the *floating* part.
**Is there a way, in flash, to get the bit representation of a Number**?

I have tried googling but either I couldn't phrase it well enough, or it isn't that easy to find.

**Edit, to clear something up:** I specifically *Number*, that is the class which represents *Floating Point Number* in Flash, not number in general. I suppose I could have wrote *Is there a way, in flash, to get the bit represebtation of a floating point number*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the only way that I can think of off the top of my head is to use a `ByteArray`

Something like this:

```
        var x:Number = 1.532;
        var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        ba.writeDouble(x);
        ba.position = 0;

        var high32bits:uint = ba.readUnsignedInt();
        var low32bits:uint = ba.readUnsignedInt();

        trace(high32bits.toString(16));  // 3ff88312
        trace(low32bits.toString(16));   // 6e978d50
```

Comment: Great idea! Awfully work-aroundish, but it works. I still wonder if there is any better way of doing it though.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to print out the binary representation (ie 2 = 10) you can use the [toString()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html#toString%28%29) function of Number and specify a radix value.

ex.

```
var x:Number = 2;
trace(x.toString(2));
```

Comment: I am afraid it doesn't work: `Number(1.532).toString(2);` and `Number(1.0).toString(2);` both give `1`.