# Binary representation of Number in IEEE double-precision format

Tags: actionscript-3, binary, numbers

I need binary representation of a Number instance. First, I tried `toString()` method of Number class with argument `2`. The result was 14-bits. (For the number 9878.658456) Then, I tried to add the Number instance to a ByteArray as follows:

```
    var b:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    var n :Number = 9878.658456;
    trace(uint(n).toString(2));
    b.writeDouble(n);
```

Then I tried to read 8 bytes:

```
    trace((b.readByte() ).toString(2));
    trace((b.readByte() ).toString(2));
    trace((b.readByte() ).toString(2));
    trace((b.readByte() ).toString(2));
    trace((b.readByte() ).toString(2));
    trace((b.readByte() ).toString(2));
    trace((b.readByte() ).toString(2));
    trace((b.readByte() ).toString(2));
```

The result isreally interesting, there are binary values which I don't know what to do with. I think I didn't understand toString method still, the API explanation is not enough for me. Any help to retrieve IEEE representation of a Number instance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bits of Number in Flash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918037/bits-of-number-in-flash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution is your own solution. I came up with this:

```
    var b:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    var n :Number = 9878.658456;
    b.writeDouble(n);
    b.position=0;
    trace((b.readByte() & 0xFF).toString(2));
    trace((b.readByte() & 0xFF).toString(2));
    trace((b.readByte() & 0xFF).toString(2));
    trace((b.readByte() & 0xFF).toString(2));
    trace((b.readByte() & 0xFF).toString(2));
    trace((b.readByte() & 0xFF).toString(2));
    trace((b.readByte() & 0xFF).toString(2));
    trace((b.readByte() & 0xFF).toString(2));
    trace((b.readByte() & 0xFF).toString(2));
```

You can check the result from [here](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/Decimal.html), it works fine.

Comment: why are you using the singed version of `readByte()` and whats up the purpose of the `and` with `255`?

Comment: I'm taking last 8 bits only, that's why I'm anding with 255.

Comment: But `readByte()` only returns 8 bits... Actionscript doesnt have a `byte` type so it's either a `uint` or an `int`.

Comment: I store the `byte`s in `int`s. When I want to use, I `AND` the `int` value with `0xFF` to consider last 8 bits only.